# Python Crawl - Amazom review crawl with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I try to crawl review data from amazon with Jupeter notebook.

But there is response 503 from server.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Here is url.
https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MWP22AM-A-AirPods-Pro/product-reviews/B07ZPC9QD4/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=

Here is my code.

```
import re, requests, csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from time import sleep

def reviews_info(div): 
    review_text = div.find("div", "a-row a-spacing-small review-data").get_text() 
    review_author = div.find("span", "a-profile-name").get_text()
    review_stars = div.find("span", "a-icon-alt").get_text() 
    on_review_date = div.find('span', 'a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date').get_text() 
    review_date = [x.strip() for x in re.sub("on ", "", on_review_date).split(",")] 

    return { "review_text" : review_text, 
            "review_author" : review_author, 
            "review_stars" : review_stars, 
            "review_date": review_date }
base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MWP22AM-A-AirPods-Pro/product-reviews/B07ZPC9QD4/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber='


reviews = [] 

NUM_PAGES = 8

for page_num in range(1, NUM_PAGES + 1): 
    print("souping page", page_num, ",", len(reviews), "data collected") 
    url = base_url + str(page_num) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml') 

    for div in soup('div', 'a-section review'): 
        reviews.append(reviews_info(div)) 
    
    sleep(30)
```

Finally I tried

```
requests.get(url)
```

The output is

```
<Response [503]>
```

And I also tried

```
requests.get(url).text()
```

The output is

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Did Amazon blocked crawl?

I'd appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon blocks the request to their servers when you attempt to crawl it, using python request lib. You can try using Selenium with chromium browser that might do the trick. Here python version of Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Answer (score 0):

I tried webdriver.

Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import requests 
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from time import sleep

review_list = []
NUM_PAGE = 8

base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MWP22AM-A-AirPods-Pro/product-reviews/B07ZPC9QD4/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber='

for num_page in range(1, NUM_PAGE + 1):
    chrome_driver = '/Users/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

    url = base_url + str(num_page)
    driver.get(url)

    src = driver.page_source
    source = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')

    driver.close()

    print("souping page", num_page, ",", len(source.find_all('div', 'a-section celwidget')), "의 data를 수집")

    for source in source.find_all('div', 'a-section celwidget'): 
        review_text = source.find("div", "a-row a-spacing-small review-data").get_text() 
        review_author = source.find("span", "a-profile-name").get_text()
        review_stars = source.find("span", "a-icon-alt").get_text() 
        on_review_date = source.find('span', 'a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date').get_text() 
        #review_date = [x.strip() for x in re.sub("on ", "", on_review_date).split(",")] 

        review = { "review_text" : review_text, 
                "review_author" : review_author, 
                "review_stars" : review_stars, 
                "review_date": on_review_date }

        review_list.append(review)
    
    sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much faster solution than using selenium/webdriver, but more costly is to use a proxy. I use proxycrawl- I'm not affiliated with them at all besides being a customer. I also recommend using a scraping framework like Scrapy. It will help in avoiding detection using variable timing between requests among other features.

You pay per successful scrape- you are not charged for unsuccessful scrapes. It's the cheapest proxy solution I've found.

You use it like this:

```
import scrapy  # scraping framework to parse data
from proxycrawl.proxycrawl_api import ProxyCrawlAPI
from datetime import datetime  # used to convert review date string into datetime object. Useful if you plan to insert into an SQL db.

api = ProxyCrawlAPI({'token': 'NON-JS TOKEN'})
apijava = ProxyCrawlAPI({'token': 'JS TOKEN'})

def start_requests(self):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'
    }
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B07ZPC9QD4/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews'  # you don't need the product title in the url
    # build proxcrawl url
    pcurl = api.buildURL(url, {})
    yield scrapy.Request(pcurl, callback=self.parse, errback=self.errback_httpbin, headers=headers, meta={'asin': 'B07ZC90D4'})


def parse(self, response):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'
    }
    reviews_count = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"]').getall()
    asin = response.meta['asin']
    asin_title = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-product_info"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h1/a/text()').get()
    if reviews_count is not None:  # review_count = number of reviews
        for review_index in range(len(reviews_count)):
            review_index += 1
            review_title = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"][' +
                                          str(review_index) + ']/div/div/div[2]/a[2]/span/text()').get()
            review_rating_string = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"][' +
                                                  str(review_index) + ']/div/div/div[2]/a[1]/@title').get()
            review_date_string = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"][' +
                                                str(
                                                    review_index) + ']/div/div/span[@data-hook="review-date"]/text()').get()
            review_body = response.xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"][' +
                                         str(review_index) + ']/div/div/div[4]/span/span/text()').get()
            review_rating = str(review_rating_string).split(' ', 1)[0]
            # get rid of the 00:00:00 time
            review_date = str(datetime.strptime(review_date_string, '%B %d, %Y')).split(' ', 1)[0]
            date_of_cur_review = datetime.strptime(review_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            
            # DO SOMETHING HERE. INSERT INTO A DB?
            #####
            
            # go to next page if there is one
            if review_index == 10:
                next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-last"]/a/@href').get()
                if next_page is not None:
                    headers = {'User-Agent': headers}
                    yield response.follow(api.buildURL('https://www.amazon.com' + next_page, {}),
                                          callback=self.parse, errback=self.errback_httpbin, headers=headers,
                                          meta={'asin': response.meta['asin']})
```